# AWS S3 buckets issues after Terraform provider upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Version 4 of the AWS Provider introduces significant changes to the aws_s3_bucket:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#changes-to-s3-bucket-drift-detection
From this version on, each parameter of the S3 bucket should be configured separately from the aws_s3_bucket resource configuration and re-imported into the Terraform state.

**Example:**

*Before:*

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "yournamehere"

  # ... other configuration ...
  acceleration_status = "Enabled"
}
```

*After:*

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "yournamehere"

  # ... other configuration ...
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_accelerate_configuration" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id
  status = "Enabled"
}
```

The number of buckets I need to reconfigure exceeds 100 which will take many days of work.
Is there a solution or a tool to make the configuration conversion faster?

Comment: See these discussions https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/23106 and https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/20433

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S3 Bucket Accelerate can be configured in either the standalone resource "aws_s3_bucket_accelerate_configuration" or with the deprecated parameter "acceleration_status" in the resource aws_s3_bucket. Configuring with both will cause inconsistencies and may overwrite configuration.

Resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket